# sqlite - принудительное указание считать выражение занчением поля, а не именем

Tags: sqlite3

Добрый день.
Столкнулся тут с интересным и для меня неожиданным поведением sqlite: у меня есть таблица где в некоторых записях значение некоторых полей могут совпадать с именами полей. Если я пытаюсь написать запрос в котором такое поле выбирается по значению, sqlite молча считает мое значение именем другого поля и выполняет совершенно другой запрос. Есть ли какой-то способ принудительно заставить его считать что некоторое выражение это именно значение поля?

Пример кода (разумеется, обрезанный насколько можно, в реальности я вообще выхватил эту проблему в сложном запросе из двух таблиц и долго не мог понять в чем дело т.к. отдельно подзапросы отрабатывали на ура, а вместе выдавали совсем не то что ожидалось):

```
create table Example(column1 text, column2 text, column3 text);
INSERT INTO "Example" VALUES ("test1","column1","I want this row, where column2 has value column1");
INSERT INTO "Example" VALUES ("aaa","aaa","But I got this one - where column1 is equal to column2");

select * from Example where column1= "column2";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам себе, решением оказалось использовать одинарную кавычку ' вместо двойной, в таком случае sqlite не кастит выражение в кавычках в название столбца